# adding text-box in column (script)

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I have this code
(in script):

```
var response = [{
      "A":"a2",
      "B":"b2",
      "C":"c2"
     },
     {
      "A":"a3",
      "B":"b3",
      "C":"c3"
    },
    {
      "A":"a4",
      "B":"b4",
      "C":"c4"
    }];

    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                $('<tr>').html(
                //"<tr>" +
                "<td>" + response[i].A + "</td><td>" + response[i].B + "</td><td>" + response[i].C + "</td>" + "</tr>").appendTo('#MyTable tbody');
        });
```

and I want to change one of column (just for exp it's will be "A") to be "edited" by text-box.
I am tring this:

```
...                `"<td><input type="text">" + response[i].A + "</td><td>" + response[i].B + "</td><td>" + response[i].C + "</td>" + "</tr>").appendTo('#MyTable tbody');`...
```

but it's not working.
any help please!

Comment: You need to assign a value to the input: <input type="text" value="'+response[i].A+'">

Comment: Watch the quotes. Since you're using `"..."` to delimit the Javascript strings, you have to use `'...'` or `\"...\"` to delimit the attribute values.

Comment: are you trying to create a new `<tr>` along with the contents..?

Comment: No, I am not trying to create a new <tr>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly,

Instead of creating `<tr>`, later adding contents to it using `html()` and finally appending to do the `<table>`, you can directly add everything altogether to the `<table>` using `append()` method.

```
 $.each(response, function(i, item) {
     $('#MyTable tbody').append("<tr>"
          +"<td><input type='text' value='"+ response[i].A +"'/> </td><td><input type='text' value='"+ response[i].B +"'/></td><td><input type='text' value='"+ response[i].C +"'/></td>"
          + "</tr>");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saying This

```
var firstcell = "<td><input type="text" value="VALUE"</td>";
firstcell = firstcell.replace('VALUE', response[i].A);
```

Use this for first cell in each Row. After that append this in whole row.